# Post values using forms and display front end

Tags: forms, drupal-8

I am very newbie to drupal 8 ,I want to add Content from back end and list in front end.

I tried to create a contact form from back end.here is my form

[image]

I don't want to send emails.only display the added item

After submit to database i want to list items.is this method is wrong?
But now the contact form not listing anything?Is my way is okay? please correct me

Answer (score 0):

Create content type with your field like Name and PDF then there will be following options to display on front page:

1. Tick the box - promoted to front page
2. Create a new Drupal page view using views to display the content on front page.